# Passing arguments to main in C using Eclipse

Tags: c, arguments, program-entry-point, atoi

I have a program in Eclipse and I need to pass some arguments into main.

More specifically, I need to pass 2 strings (which are numbers) and are needed to call some other functions. Here is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = atoi(argv[0]);
    size_t size = (size_t)(atoi(argv[1]));
    char **commands = getCommands(n, size);
    return 0;
}
```

What getCommands doesn't matter, as my questions are:

1) Is my use of `atoi` correct here? Let me remind you that the arguments I want to pass is an array of strings, where the strings are numbers. Also, will the `int` from `atoi` get successfully converted into `size_t` just by casting it?

2) What exactly do I have to put in the arguments box in Eclipse? 
When I pass : `2 {"3","50"}` it doesn't work. Aren't I supposed to pass first the number of arguments in the array, and then the array of strings? I am a bit confused. This also goes to passing arguments from the command line, as I guess it has to have the same format? I don't know how to do that either.

Thanks.

Comment: `argv[0]` is, by convention, the **name of the program**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Sure, that's all fine (except for the `argv` indices as described below), if you're assuming your inputs are valid numbers. If not, `atoi` will return `0`.

2) You're not meant to pass arguments to `main` -- instead, you pass arguments to the program, and the OS comes up with the right arguments to pass to `main`. So rather than passing `2 {"3","50"}`, you just pass in `3 50`. In your `main` function, you'll see that `argc == 3`, `argv[0]` is the name of the program, `argv[1]` is the string `"3"`, and `argv[2]` is the string `"50"`.